# Could not find RippleDrawable

Tags: android, rippledrawable

I want to create a ripple dynamically in code.

Code:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      buyButton.setBackground(getPressedColorRippleDrawable(primaryColor, darkerVariant));
}

public static RippleDrawable getPressedColorRippleDrawable(int color, int darkerVariant) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]
                        {new int[]{}},
                new int[]
                        {darkerVariant}
        );
        return new RippleDrawable(colorStateList, new ColorDrawable(color), null);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This works on Lollipop but makes the app crash on my GNEX (4.3).
Error:

> Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method fragments.ProductDetailFragment.getPressedColorRippleDrawable
>
> 07-17 12:57:45.757  30992-30992/com.comizzo.ginsonline E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> java.lang.VerifyError: fragments/ProductDetailFragment

But RippleDrawable is never used on Gnex because code isn't executed.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you need to return a Drawable instead of a RippleDrawable in `getPressedColorRippleDrawable`. Otherwise, on pre-lollipop devices, you will get a VerifyError.

Answer (score 4):

That code is indeed not being executed. The app crashes because you're receiving a `java.lang.VerifyError`. Try performing a `Project → Clean` if you're using Eclipse or `Build → Rebuild project` if you're using Android Studio.