# Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable' android studio 2.2.3

Tags: java, android, material-design

> Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

Comment: Please, i need some help, cause im facing this problem for a while.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find RippleDrawable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474297/could-not-find-rippledrawable)

Answer (score 0):

check your themes config. all themes must have a parent from AppCompat.

like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

if you not specify the parent, the appcompat lib would have no effect.