# Android Studio App has stopped working

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

so I am using Android Studio 2.2 to work on an App and when I run on my emulator after the APK has been installed the screen went black and it says that my App has stopped working shortly after.

Btw I am running on an API 19 emulator and my compileSDKversion is 25, minSDKversion is 16 and targetSDKversion is 19.

This was at my Logcat, please take a look and tell me what it means:

```
06-07 04:32:50.551 3900-3900/com.example.justin_poo.cncapplication E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

Any help would be nice!! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find RippleDrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474297/could-not-find-rippledrawable)

Comment: show us some efforts!

Comment: more code would be really helpful in order for people to help you. as for the first thought, search and find in your code usage of Tint (changing colors) and you will find issue location over there probably.