# My progress dialog is stuck at signIn screen and not starting new activity

Tags: java, android

This is debug report

```
05-14 12:40:35.931 8337-8337/com.example.admin.clicknorderserver E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
05-14 12:40:35.931 8337-8337/com.example.admin.clicknorderserver E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
05-14 12:40:35.931 8337-8337/com.example.admin.clicknorderserver E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
05-14 12:40:35.931 8337-8337/com.example.admin.clicknorderserver E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
05-14 12:40:57.171 8337-8337/com.example.admin.clicknorderserver E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

This is my `signIn.java` where I declared progress dialog:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    edtPhone=(MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
    edtPassword=(MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    btnSignIn=(FButton)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
    //Init firebase
    db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    users=db.getReference("User");
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

signInUser(edtPhone.getText().toString(),edtPassword.getText().toString());
        }

        private void signInUser(String phone, String password) {
            final ProgressDialog mDialog=new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            mDialog.show();
            final String localPhone=phone;
            final String  localPassword=password;
            users.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.child(localPhone).exists())
                    {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        User 
user=dataSnapshot.child(localPhone).getValue(User.class);
                        user.setPhone(localPhone);
                        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(user.getIsStaff()))
                        {
                            if (user.getPassword().equals(localPassword))
                            {
                                Intent login =new 
                                Intent(SignIn.this,Home.class);
                                Common.currentUser=user;
                                startActivity(login);
                                finish();

                            }
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this,"Wrong password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this,"Login with staff account",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this,"User not exist in database..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

    }
}
```

If any further information is required then I'll edit the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474297/could-not-find-rippledrawable

Comment: i think user is getting null over there ,try to print the value of user

Comment: put a `log` inside all of your conditions and see at what point is it struck.

Comment: if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                    {
                        mDialog.dismiss();

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        signInUser(edtPhone.getText().toString(),edtPassword.getText().toString());
    }
    private void signInUser(String phone, String password) {
        final ProgressDialog mDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        mDialog.show();
        final String localPhone=phone;
        Log.i("TAG","phone"+phone);
        final String  localPassword=password;
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String password = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue().toString();
                String phone = dataSnapshot.child("phone").getValue().toString();
                if(localPhone.equals(phone) && localPassword.equals(password))
                {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    // your Intent here
                }else
                {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                   //your code here
                }
            }
           @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.i("tag","hi"+databaseError);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: it seems you do not have permission to read and write without authentication you can check this by putting Log in onCancelled ().

Comment: you can give permission by going to your firebase console then rules and then make read:true and write:true