# How to resolve this error in libraries?

Tags: android

```
 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method 
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
  E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 
'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$1', referenced from method 
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.<init>
 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced 
from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onDraw
 E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced 
from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35908070/6207294

Comment: Can you share some more context about this?

Comment: No need  this code i am check this code is not suitable for my device

Answer (score 0):

On newer Android versions you need to return a `Drawable` and not a `RippleDrawable`.

Comment: I am using 4.4 but this is overlapping

Comment: Have you imported the classes? I can not help you without the code.

Comment: @abdulbasit Don't suggest an edit to James' answer with your code. [Edit your _question_](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51601995/edit) instead.

Comment: sorry i am using this website first time sorry

Comment: @abdul basit, if this answer was correct, please mark it as correct so future readers know this has been solved.